# select statement

Tags: sql-server

what select statement would I use to add the excel spreadsheet to an existing table, as i am getting an error trying to create a new table on the database? please can you assist me.
Thanks

Comment: Hi Fiona - you need to give a bit more detail in your question as to what tools you're using...eg Enterprise Manager? And any steps you've tried. More detail = more chance of an answer.

Comment: Hi Kev
I am using Enterprise Manager - i am trying to import an excel spreadsheet, i have done exactly what Dave said but i still get an error while doing the import, taught it was an authority error but i guess not i think the error lies somewhere with the xls, Thanks

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472638/how-do-i-import-an-excel-spreadsheet-into-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

Fiona --

You're probably using the wrong tools here.  You probably want to use a tool called SQL Server Integration Services to get your data into SQL Server.  You can do this by right-clicking on your database in SQL Server Enterprise Manager, selecting "Tasks". then "Import Data".  You'll probably need to do some more research on what you're doing in order to accomplish what you want.

Comment: If you dont have SSIS in your version of SQL Server, you can use DTS.

Comment: I have done the exact thing that you are telling me but i still getting an error, Maybe i am not have permission to do it, Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

you can also do it with OPENROWSET

```
INSERT INTO SOMETABLE SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET( 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\testing.xls','SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```