# How to connect Excel to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, database, excel, database-connection, connection-string

I have data in an Excel spreadsheet with 9 columns. How do I fetch this data into an existing table in SQL Server?

By using the Import & Export tool, I need to create a new table which I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SSIS. Source=Excel, destination = your table.

Make sure they both have the same column name.

also you can acte [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20085249/import-excel-spreadsheet-data-to-an-existing-sql-table)

Answer (score 1):

With Import Export tool also you can import data to the existing table. At the time of Importing data option is available whether you want to delete all existing table and import fresh data or append data.