# Inserting data into an db table from another db table – (Classic ASP)

Tags: sql-server, excel, asp-classic

**Project details: Classic ASP with SQL 2012.**

I have an Excel file with only two columns (“F1” & “F2”) containing about 3000 records.

I also have an SQL2012 table named “BACKUPP” with 3 columns (“ID” “KODIKOS” “APOTHEMA”).

I want to insert all the data from the Excel to the “BACKUPP” table.
I have already successfully connected to both Excel & sql db, with the following way:

FOR THE EXCEL:

```
Dim RS_EXCEL
Dim RS_EXCEL_cmd
Dim RS_EXCEL_numRows
Set RS_EXCEL_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
RS_EXCEL_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_connnectt_STRING
RS_EXCEL_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ['Website stock$']" RS_EXCEL_cmd.Prepared = true
Set RS_EXCEL = RS_EXCEL_cmd.Execute
RS_EXCEL_numRows = 0
```

Using the following connection string:

```
MM_connnectt_STRING = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\OLA\SITES\SuperCleanerWINHOST\BACK\file.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"";"
```

FOR THE SQL DB:

```
Dim RS_SQL
Dim RS_SQL_cmd
Dim RS_SQL_numRows
Set RS_SQL_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
RS_SQL_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_syndesi_STRING
RS_SQL_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.BACKUPP" 
RS_SQL_cmd.Prepared = true
Set RS_SQL = RS_SQL_cmd.Execute
RS_SQL_numRows = 0
```

Using the following connection string:

```
MM_syndesi_STRING = "dsn=DSN_supercle_dsn;uid=DB_107185_cleanerdb_user;pwd=XXXXX;"
```

Both of my connections works perfect locally. I have also test them online and also working without any problem.

So I can easily retrieve data without any problem, from Excel & SQL db.
My problem is that I don’t know the way to insert all the data from the Excel db to sql db.

I want the “F1” column of the Excel db to be inserted to the “KODIKOS” column
And
The “F2” column of the Excel db to be inserted to the “APOTHEMA” column.

My programming knowledge is not good. I am mostly designer. 
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Throw away your Dreamweaver generated code.  If you're inserting data then you're better off using an insert query rather than opening another recordset.  Here's how I would do this:

```
<%
Dim conn1, conn2, rs, rssql, insertsql

Set conn1 = Server.Createobject("ADODB.Connection")
Set conn2 = Server.Createobject("ADODB.Connection")

conn1.open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\OLA\SITES\SuperCleanerWINHOST\BACK\file.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"";"

conn2.open "dsn=DSN_supercle_dsn;uid=DB_107185_cleanerdb_user;pwd=XXXXX;"

set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rssql = "SELECT * FROM ['Website stock$']"
rs.open rssql,conn1,0,1 

Do While Not rs.eof

insertsql = "INSERT into dbo.BACKUPP (KODIKOS, APOTHEMA) values ('" & rs("F1") & "', '" & rs("F2") & "')"

'Response.write insertsql
conn2.execute(insertsql)

rs.movenext
Loop

rs.close
conn1.close
conn2.close

Set rs = Nothing
Set conn1 = Nothing
Set conn2 = Nothing
%>
```

Basically what's happening is that we're looping through a recordset inserting each row from the excel document into the SQL database.

I've added the commented out `response.write insertsql` statement because it's very easy to make mistakes when you're inserting recordset variables into a SQL string, and it's a good idea to read the actual SQL which your script outputs before you try to execute it.  To do this you uncomment the response.write statement and comment the conn2.execute statement.

I'm assuming this is a "behind the scenes" page.  If it is public facing then you need to look at how to protect against SQL injection attaccks

Comment: The minute I saw it was the classic DW `MM_` code I walked away...sorry.

Comment: Plus if they have SQL Server they [could just do all that inside T-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/472638/692942), no need to Classic ASP at all.

Comment: Your help is truly appreciated John. I will try it with your way. Thanks again!

Comment: @user2986570 so doing all inside SQL Server without need for external script doesn't appeal?

Comment: @user2986570 - re your comma as decimal point issue, VBScript has a simple replace function.  In place of `rs("F2")` you could use `replace(rs("F2"),",",".")`  It looks confusing because VBS uses commas as separators.  If you were replacing "$" with "£" then it would look like `replace(rs("F2"),"$","£")`

Comment: If you want to try cdbl then the syntax is `cdbl(rs("F2"))`

Comment: @John  SOLVED with:  replace(rs("F2"),",",".")
MANY, MANY THANK for your valuable help!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

For tasks like this, you are far better harnessing the power of SQL Server directly to do the data import, this is what [`OPENROWSET`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312(v=sql.110).aspx) was designed for.

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.BACKUPP
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\OLA\SITES\SuperCleanerWINHOST\BACK\file.xls','SELECT * FROM [Website stock$]')
```

The awesome thing about this approach is you can still call it from Classic ASP just wrap it in a Stored Procedure and call through the `ADODB.Command` object, something like;

```vb
Dim cmd, conn_string
conn_string = "dsn=DSN_supercle_dsn;uid=DB_107185_cleanerdb_user;pwd=XXXXX;"

Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With cmd
  .ActiveConnection = conn_string
  .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
  .CommandText = "dbo.YourStoredProc"
  Call .Execute()
End With
```