# How to import an entire excel spreadsheet table into a table on a SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

My company currently has a script written in `VBA` in `MS Access` that fetches data from a series of excel spreadsheets and updates a table on a SQL server. As it stands, the VBA script imports the rows individually, using a `For-loop` to loop through the rows and building / executing a series of `INSERT` commands on the SQL server. This is extremely slow, and problematic since we need to update the tables regularly.

My question is, how can we bulk-import an entire excel spreadsheet into a table on the SQL server using VBA in access?

Is there a command in SQL that will do this automatically? And if so, will it be any quicker than updating it on a row-by-row basis? I have checked out various articles online, but have so far found a workable solution.

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I import an excel spreadsheet into SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472638/how-do-i-import-an-excel-spreadsheet-into-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer but i think there are two lines of investigation you should consider:

**Option 1 - SSIS**:

1. right click on DB in SQL server (inside SSMS)
2. select: tasks: import data
3. follow this wizard but make sure to select save SSIS package near the end of this process
4. save it to you rfile system (there are many ways to do all this but this is one way)
5. run the package whenever you want from command line using DTEXEC:

   `DTEXEC /FILE ImportPackacge.dtsx`

if you follow this option you can compare how fast it runs when you do the import manually in the wizard, this will give you a rough idea of how fast it will run and is normally much faster than individual inserting.

Note you can create a whole load process in an SSIS package  that can also transform and verify data.

step by step example of importing - without saving: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/get-started-with-this-simple-example-of-the-import-and-export-wizard

Saving packages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/save-and-run-package-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard

Running a package: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/run-integration-services-ssis-packages

DTEXEC - command line tool for running packages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/dtexec-utility

**Option 2 - BULK INSERT**:

Look into the bulk insert command and how it may be applied in VBA code

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/bulk-import-and-export-of-data-sql-server

note that article talks about other bulk import techniques that may be worth looking into.

**there are many finer points to each option.. but depending on your skill level / knowledge this may be all the info you need to get a solution going.**

Also note there are soooo many ways of doing this; access and excel and sql server each have ways of doing some or all of the heavy lifting here. I would find the ones that are most familiar to you first and check their speed to see if it's good enough.

I may actually start by trying this solution (from the comment posted by FunThomas) that opens the excel file as a table and directly copies as its very simple for anyone who know sql to understand:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/473019/359135

Comment: BULK INSERT requires INSERT and ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS permissions for SQL Server. Most DBAs are not going to grant that (mine certainly didn't), so creating an SSIS package is probably the only viable option for most developers.