# What is the best way to insert 1 million records into a DB table from an excel sheet?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created 1 million insert queries using excel in order to insert the records into an SQL table (SQL Server). I was informed that I can't not simply copy and paste the queries into SQL Server since it will definitely crash.

The best way should be to insert in batches but I'm pretty sure there is a more efficient and automated way for me to insert that many records.

So can someone please give me a solution for the matter at hand?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import an entire excel spreadsheet table into a table on a SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47134514/how-to-import-an-entire-excel-spreadsheet-table-into-a-table-on-a-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

Use Sql Server import and export wizard[image]

Comment: Does it accept Microsoft Excel with queries in it or is there a specific format?

Comment: This will not work with queries in Excel sheet. For importing data using Excel sheet it required to add only data in the sheet

Comment: So, all i have to do is have the data in an excel sheet with the first row being the column names?

Comment: yes,try it if any problem occurs let know.

Comment: @MohammadAlBaba, you can also add column name and also add without column name. Both are possible. 1) With column name in first row, you can directly crate new table which will be generated with column names given in sheet. 2) Without column name, you need to specify columns in order as your table